# Symbol SPT-1800 Java Barcode Scanner

Tags: java, barcode, palm-os

Does anybody know if its possible to write a barcode scanning application for the SPT-1800 in Java?

I don't know how to program the Old School Palm OS.. so java would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you will have to write a Palm app in C to control that model.

See the [Software Development Kit (SDK), v. 4.10](http://support.symbol.com/support/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=10387&sliceId=&dialogID=101782009&stateId=1%200%20101768992) and [FAQ: Where Can I find the Palm SDK & Development Tool?](http://support.symbol.com/support/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=MCD-00278&sliceId=SAL_Public&dialogID=101782009&stateId=1%200%20101768992) for more information.

The Motorola/Symbol sites are not very intuitive so here's a link to all of the [SPT1800 support documents](http://support.symbol.com/support/search.do?languages=&rwTarget=%2FrfPlayerWidget.do&searchMode=GuidedSearch&searchString=&productLine=SG_MOBILECOMPUTERS_1_1&product=SG_SPT1800_1_2&document=&cmd=search&productFamily=&contextType=gs).

The SDK's are usually very good and get you up and running with a sample application pretty quickly.

I had hoped to use Java for the MC3000 and MC9000 series recently but it appears Motorola/Symbol has stopped releasing updated Java SDK's for those devices and are concentrating on the .NET SDK now.

The Java SDK's also require additional licensing of the JVM from 3rd party vendors which considerably adds to the final cost of deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that [Waba/SuperWaba](http://www.wabasoft.com/) would be your best bet for an older PalmOS device.